# Override persistence.xml property

Tags: glassfish, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

What would be the proper way to override EclipseLink `persistence.xml` property when running application on Glassfish application server?

We need some properties to be configured in a separate configuration file which would be available to a client.

I didn't find any EclipseLink-specific classes which accept some user properties. I only found Glassfish PersistenceUnitLoader class which could be tweaked in order to achieve that. But this would be an ugly hack :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own EntityManager at runtime:

```
Map map = new HashMap();  

map.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "password");  
map.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "root");  

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPU",map);  
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(map);
```

Some eclipselink property names:

```
  <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="DERBY"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/02DB;create=true"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, but as I said, I run my app in container, so I inject EntityManager instead of creating it myself. For Java SE your approach would be sufficient, I agree. But thanks for the suggestion, anyway.